# Finding a Limit of a Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm struggling to find the limit of the following function in $\mathbb{C}$.

$\lim_{z\to0} (\frac{1}{e^{z}-1}-\frac{1}{z})$

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Convert your expression into a single fraction and use the Taylor expansion of $e^z$ centered at $0$.

Comment: Thanks! Got it!